# Mellanox libvma: How to receive packet timestamp which is comparable to userspace time?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, networking

With default Linux sockets, receiving timestamps worked for me like this:

```
char ctrl[CMSG_SPACE(sizeof(struct timeval))];

struct msghdr msg;
struct iovec iov;
msg.msg_control = (char*)ctrl;
msg.msg_controllen = sizeof(ctrl);
msg.msg_name = &cfg->ifaddr;
msg.msg_namelen = sizeof(cfg->ifaddr);

msg.msg_iov = &iov;
msg.msg_iovlen = 1;
iov.iov_base = buffer;
iov.iov_len = BUFFER_SIZE;

struct timeval time_user, time_kernel;
struct cmsghdr *cmsg = (struct cmsghdr*)&ctrl;

const int64_t read_bytes = recvmsg(igmp_socket_fd, &msg, 0);
if(read_bytes == -1) {
    return;
}

gettimeofday(&time_user, NULL);

if(cmsg->cmsg_level == SOL_SOCKET) {
    memcpy(&time_kernel, CMSG_DATA(cmsg), sizeof(struct timeval));
    const double timediff = (time_user.tv_sec - time_kernel.tv_sec) * 1000000 + (time_user.tv_usec - time_kernel.tv_usec);
}
```

But with

`vma_api->recvfrom_zcopy(socket_fd, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, &flags, &sa, &sock_len);`

there is no way to pass a `struct msghdr` (there is also no `recvmsg`-function). The manual (https://www.mellanox.com/related-docs/prod_acceleration_software/VMA_8_6_10_User_Manual.pdf) on page 38 only tells me that I need a PTP-daemon running.

Does anyone know if and how I can receive a timestamp with libvma which is comparable to `gettimeofday` in userspace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like, `recvmsg` is overwritten by libvma (in case it is pre-loaded with `LD_PRELOAD`) so my example code in the post above can be used as well. Furthermore, `vma_cyclic_buffer_read` supplies a hardware-timestamp (which is usually synchronized with user-space time by the setting `VMA_HW_TS_CONVERSION=3`) for the first packet of the buffer (not for every packet unfortunately):

```
struct vma_completion_cb_t vma_completion;
memset(&vma_completion, 0, sizeof(struct vma_completion_cb_t));
vma_completion.comp_mask = VMA_CB_MASK_TIMESTAMP; /* important */

const int ret = vma_api->vma_cyclic_buffer_read(ring_fd, &vma_completion, 100, 5000, flags);
/* ... */
struct timeval usr_timeval;
gettimeofday(&usr_timeval, NULL);

const uint16_t timediff_us = calc_us_timeval_spec_diff(&usr_timeval, &vma_completion.hw_timestamp);
```